# "Is there any news" or "are there any news"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is better? Which is grammatically correct?

> - Is there any news about my candidacy?
> - Are there any news about my candidacy?

Comment: news  (no̅o̅z, nyo̅o̅z) pl.n. (used with a **sing. verb**) http://www.thefreedictionary.com/news

Comment: As an aside, there must be no space before a question mark in English (and indeed in the vast majority of other languages).

Answer (score 7):

I don't agree with the answer provided by @vickyace. News is uncountable and cannot be countable. So to answer your question, the first is the correct example.